# Connected vs Irreducible Subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am asking if there is any particular criterion for a connected component of given variety to be irreducible (you can assume suitable conditions on the variety, in fact I am studying sub-varieties of moduli spaces)

thanks

Comment: What about normality ?

Comment: Sometimes smoothness is easier to check than normality, and of course it also implies irreducibility of connected components.

Comment: Does normality implies irreducibility of connected components?

Comment: Yes $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \       $